# thousands separator in jquery for wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have this code for a Jquery function for one plugin...

http://solteda.com/wprabiensa/wp-content/plugins/Amortiza/amortizascript.js

**I want the result to be thousands separator**

This is the HTML content

```
<div align="center">
    <div class="AMortCal">
        <label>Importe del pr&eacute;stamo($)</label>
        <input type="text" name="prestamo" id="prestamo" placeholder="Digite la cantidad" />
        <p> </p>
        <label>Plazo de la hipoteca(Anual)</label>
        <input type="text" name="anos" id="anos" placeholder="Cantidad de a&ntilde;os" />
        <p> </p>
        <label>Tasa De Inter&eacute;s (%) Anual</label>
        <input type="text" name="interes" id="interes" placeholder="Digite tasa de inter&eacute;s" />
        <p> </p>
        <input type="button" name="calcularprestamos" id="calcularprestamos" class="boton" value="Calcular" />
        <input type="button" name="resetear" id="resetear" value="Resetear" class="boton"/>
        <br class="clear"/>
        <p> </p>
        <div class="resultado" id="resultado">Cuotas a pagar</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post all relevant code in the question itself. That link will rot making question useless in the future

Comment: I can not put as much code